# MS Access select fields from Textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with only one column, and before field it is plus sign, so that if I push it I see other columns and rows. Sorry for such an explanation, didn't find how it is named properly.

So, the question is how to create a table with some columns from this table.
My attempt was:

```
SELECT ID, Name INTO NewTable
FROM Table
WHERE [Table.Column] = 'Value';
```

or even

```
SELECT ID, Name INTO NewTable
FROM Table.Column
WHERE [Table.Column] = 'Value';
```

Help please.

P.S. MS Access 2013

Comment: I didn't understand whats wrong with your first  query?

Comment: Not query, it's table.
It will better explain screen
[link](http://i.imgur.com/uLgNmNl.png)
So I need a new table with just 2 first columns, and now from whole this table, but only from first row of it.

Comment: What is `table.column` referring to? try "value" with double quotes. You mention a 'textbox' in your title, has this anything to do with a textbox on a form?

Comment: In this screen table.column is whole column with name 'kaubagrupp'.
It copies me just row name, not a data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably after something like this:

```
SELECT ID, [Name] 
INTO NewTable
FROM Table
WHERE Table.[Column] = 'Value';
```

Comment: It asks for a parrameter value on both ID and name, but afterall gives new table with only one row, where there is that values that I inserted in a form.

Comment: Well, then your source table doesn't have these columns. You may need a join to the child table if the fields exist in that.

Comment: I've added a screen above (in comments), will you see on it and help? I have no idea how to write it out.